# Undefined variable $followings overtrue/laravel-follow

Tags: php, laravel, view, laravel-9

I'm getting this error however using dd($followings); in the home controller, the date is displayed, but when I try to foreach the view, I get this error.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

> Undefined variable $followings

**HomeController**

```
public function userFollow($username)
{
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->firstOrFail();

    $posts = Post::where('user_id', $user->id)->simplePaginate(3);
    $user = User::find($user->id);
    $followings = $user->followings()->with('followable')->get();

    dd($followings);
    return view('/@', compact('user'), compact('posts'), compact('followings'));

}
```

**view @.blade.php**

```
@foreach($followings as $following)

 {{$following->id}}

@endforeach
```

**dd($followings); returns**

```
  #attributes: array:7 [▼
    "id" => 60
    "user_id" => 5
    "followable_type" => "App\Models\User"
    "followable_id" => 9
    "accepted_at" => "2022-12-20 20:36:49"
    "created_at" => "2022-12-20 20:36:49"
    "updated_at" => "2022-12-20 20:36:49"
```

Comment: Try to dd($user) first. Besides a find() function you also have findOrFail(), maybe that will help

Comment: Try to add {{ dd($followings) }} raw at the top of the view(blade.php) to see what you get.

Comment: `view` only takes 3 arguments ... `compact` can take multiple arguments ... you should be having that array passed as the second argument to `view`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `compact()` like this

```
return view('/@', compact('user', 'posts', 'followings'));
```

Or use `with()`

```
return view('/@')->with(['user' => $user, 'posts' => $posts, 'followings' => $followings]);
```